# innerHTML is still counting a tag?

Tags: javascript, html, web, innerhtml

I have made a typewriter effect that will first type a string, then delete it again. Shown here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FZAVKJW3BPSV

However, as you can see by the output there is a '>' tag that will not go away! I have tried everything.

I have pasted the function that is at fault below:

```
    function removeType(i,isTag,text,str2) {
      text = str2.slice(0, --i);

      if(text == 0){
        return;
      }
      document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = text;

      var char = text.slice(-1);
      if( char === '>' ) isTag = true;
      if( char === '<' ) isTag = false;

      if (isTag) return removeType(i,isTag,text,str2);
      setTimeout(function() { removeType(i,isTag,text,str2);}, 100);

    }
```

Comment: Please post your relevant “*[mcve]*” code in your question, don’t just post a link and expect us to go see.

Comment: Your issue is here `if( char === '<' ) isTag = false;` change that to true `if( char === '<' ) isTag = true;` in both places

Comment: @Ingus, be aware that the direction of string parsing is opposite in those functions, so the effect of a `<` will have to be different.

Comment: @trincot i tested it and it seemed to be working

Comment: In function `removeType` change the `if` to `if (isTag || char === '<')`.

Comment: @Ignus, logically it is wrong: when you go backwards and find a `<`, you're going *out* of a tag, so `isTag` needs to be set to `false` at that moment.

Comment: Even if `if( char === '>' )` is true, the following `if( char === '<' )` will be false and will reset `isTag` to `false`…

Comment: When you disable the tag, it has not yet passed, it is displayed. It must be done further on

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FZAW1HWOEQ3T

Comment: @trincot the answer was great! Thanks.

Comment: @Lortet your answer seemed to work fine too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
    function removeType(i,isTag,text,str2) {
      text = str2.slice(0, --i);

      if(text == 0){
        return;
      }
      document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = text;

      var char = text.slice(-1);
      if( char === '>' ) isTag = true;
      if( char === '<' ) isTag = false;

      if (isTag) return removeType(i,isTag,text,str2);
      setTimeout(function() { removeType(i,isTag,text,str2);}, 100);

    }
```

by

```
    function removeType(i,isTag,text,str2) {
      text = str2.slice(0, --i);

      document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = text;
      if(text === ''){
        return;
      }

      var char = text.slice(-1);
      if( char === '>' ) isTag = true;

      if (isTag) {
        if( char === '<' ) isTag = false;
        return removeType(i,isTag,text,str2);
      }
      setTimeout(function() { removeType(i,isTag,text,str2);}, 100);

    }
```

There are two identical problems.

If you quit when the string is empty but before update display, then a character will remain (And string == "" not 0)

If you say the tag is finished while you are still processing it, it will appear. You have to remember that the tag is finished for the next round. Several methods are possible, but the one I propose does not create new variables.

You can also use this to remove tags :

```
  str2.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
```

or (Warning, the string must be trusted) :

```
  var str2 = "Hello Stackoverflow<span class='punc'>?</span>";

  const el = document.createElement('p');
  el.innerHTML = str2;
  str2 = el.innerText;
```

```js
window.onload = function(){
      var str2 = "Hello Stackoverflow<span class='punc'>?</span>";
      i = 0;
      j = 0;
      isTag = false;
      text = "";
      type(i,isTag,text,str2);
    }
      function type(i,isTag,text,str2){
        text = str2.slice(0, ++i);
        if (text === str2) {
          setTimeout(function() { removeType(i,isTag,text,str2);}, 2000);
          return;
        }
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = text;

        var char = text.slice(-1);
        if( char === '<' ) isTag = true;
        if( char === '>' ) isTag = false;

        if (isTag) return type(i,isTag,text,str2);
        setTimeout(function() { type(i,isTag,text,str2);}, 80);
    }

    function removeType(i,isTag,text,str2) {
      text = str2.slice(0, --i);

      document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = text;

      if(text === ''){
        return;
      }
      
      var char = text.slice(-1);
      if( char === '>' ) isTag = true;
    
      if (isTag) {
        if( char === '<' ) isTag = false;
       return removeType(i,isTag,text,str2);
      }
      setTimeout(function() { removeType(i,isTag,text,str2);}, 100);

    }
```

```html
<div id="test"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the function `removeType` is that you do not get into the `if (isTag)` body when you just parsed a `<`. So that will keep that character visible until the next timer tick.

Fix it by changing that `if` condition to:

```
if (isTag || char === '<')
```

Unrelated, but you should also change:

```
if(text == 0){
```

.... because that condition will never be true (unless the first character of your full text is "0"). Change it to:

```
if (!text.length){
```